# open database photos of human faces with age

Tags: data-request, images, faces

Is there an open database with photos of the human face, with related data such as age, sex or ethnicity, but I am most interested in age.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to go through the list yourself to find the dataset that includes age of the face, or other demographics.

---

1. There is a long list of face databases at the [Face Recognition Home Page](http://www.face-rec.org/databases/). Searching for " age " on the page.

> When benchmarking an algorithm it is recommendable to use a standard test data set for researchers to be able to directly compare the results. While there are many databases in use currently, the choice of an appropriate database to be used should be made based on the task given (aging, expressions, lighting etc). Another way is to choose the data set specific to the property to be tested (e.g. how algorithm behaves when given images with lighting changes or images with different facial expressions). If, on the other hand, an algorithm needs to be trained with more images per class (like LDA), Yale face database is probably more appropriate than FERET.

---

2. Results of searching "facial recognition" on datahub.io - [LINK](http://datahub.io/dataset?q=facial%20recognition&sort=score%20desc%2C%20metadata_modified%20desc)

Comment: Also https://twitter.com/hmason/status/598173877173395456?s=02)